# How to arrange the text in the new logo of programmers.SE and its meta?

Tags: website-design, logo, typography, critique, composition

Our old logo:

[image: old logo]

and its meta version:

[image: old meta logo]

need to be updated with our new name.  [We were offered](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8254/131624):

[image: proposed new logo]

which has a great mug icon, monitor art, and font.

Just not sure about the composition.  The text seems unbalanced and is starting to crowd the eye pleasing whitespace.  Especially when you still need to add meta. They offered no example of a meta logo.

I [proposed](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8257/131624):

[image: own logo version]

As well as a meta variant:

[image]

Are there any objective concerns I'm ignoring here?

Comment: The first image offered is better IMHO. The double line version makes things cramped i like the empty space of the first.  Not so sure how well a hand written drafting font relates to software engineering but seems to work visually fine. Not thematically necceserily.

Comment: It would be interesting if some of the designers here send you some proposals. Probably in a meta thread. I'll try to submit some variations.

Comment: @Rafael Sounds good.  They indicated they want to finalize the change soon so we don't have much time.

Comment: @Rafael haven't heard from you.  If you've started another thread please point me to it.

Comment: Sorry CandidedOrange. It was a complicated weekend. Let us continue on this thread.

Comment: Will the background flow-chart-y doodles be going away if the main graphic loses the hand-drawn style? Also, are the /* elements important?

Comment: @1006a You're the first one to bring up the doodles. I think you're right about that being coupled to the hand-drawn theme.  It's meant to make it feel like a whiteboard.  I've never really felt like it achieved that. It's supposed to look like an half erased diagram.  My eyes keep turning it into computer cabling.

Comment: I think the readability of all the first versions is really bad. Yours with the double line is much better. And for me personally hand drawn things + programming don't really go hand in hand.

Comment: I agree, it took me a couple of looks to figure out what was going on with it. I understand the concept, but I keep wanting to *finish* erasing it ;-).

Comment: @CandiedOrange: I had never even *noticed* the background doodles! Wow!

Comment: @CandiedOrange: and FYI I like your design more than the current one. Though I'm still not sure I like the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposal is an improovement.

Probably the image needs fo be more modern and fresher. The flat design it is staying for a bit so how about using that, and let me use a robust font.

The 3 lines of vapor are cool and could indicate lines of code. Let us forget for a moment a normal monitor, and let us simplify that with just a screen. The smaller rectangle could be the base of a screen or could be a mobile device.

And now the text is integrated with the image.

[image]

---

### Updated

Here are the adapted recomendations. A less rounded mug, a Meta version, and a thin line of the monitor :o)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(I need to repair the far border of the G)

---

### Update 2

A bit rounded mug

[image]
[image]

### Update 3

Less bright red and the Meta highlighted.

[image]

[image]

A test:

[image]

Comment: Seeing this, I realize the "hand drawn doodle style" is actually *totally* inappropriate :) The monitor could use a bit more body, though. Perhaps add an outline around? And not such a round bottom on that cup, while you're there.

Comment: What does the meta version of this look like?

Comment: I agree that the hand drawn font is bad but i like the layered look that tge outlined monitor makes on the original.

Comment: joojaa, what is tge?

Comment: @Rafael a typo for the. The nwe mug is a bit too uniformly square.

Comment: Oh. I will go and shop another mug later :o)

Comment: @Rafael the meta version should have the site name grayed and the meta highlighted.

Comment: The meta highlighted. Check.